Integrating EclipseStore with Micronaut and Azure
I try to use EclipseStore to store my data in Azure.
I've followed this tutorial and I am able to store data locally with this application.yml config:
eclipsestore:
  storage:
    versions:
      root-class: package.name.EntityContainer
      storage-directory: build/dependency-storage
      channel-count: 1

If I add the dependencies for azure and replace the application.yml storage-directory config with connection-string: DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=storageAccountName;AccountKey=ABC==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net
implementation("com.azure:azure-storage-blob:12.26.1")
implementation("org.eclipse.store:afs-azure-storage:1.3.2")

It doesn't throw an error but it doesn't even tries connecting to Azure. (Firewall is also not the reason)

I've tried the connection as described above and also this one (which one this the correct one for this usage?) DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;BlobEndpoint=https://storageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/;AccountName=storageAccountName;AccountKey=ABC==

It seems like Micronaut doesn't support EclipseStore and Azure Blob storage (see their github docs

As of now, the Micronaut integration of EclipseStore does not support Azure Blob Storage.

I've added a pull request for adding the feature

The PR got merged and is now part of Micronaut 4.6.0 and/or Micronaut EclipseStore 1.7.0
